# What is datum ?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to solve an assignment with Set in python. I was given a demo set and asked to write a single program that will calculate the sum of all numbers, the number of datum, and the average for the entire dataset.

## I am not quite sure about the datum, can anyone help me to explain the term "datum" in this particular situation.

Comment: How about google? https://www.gingersoftware.com/english-online/spelling-book/confusing-words/data-datum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"datum" is the singular of "data". In other words, you are being asked how many numbers are in the dataset. You need this, as well as the sum, in order to obtain the average.